# Replacing the Java cacerts folder with a new one

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, certificate

I have a long time working with a Java Web App in eclipse and i never make change in the java cacerts directory.

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\security
and
C:\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\security
```

But now, i have to work with new web app in eclipse and they giving to me a cacerts file, i have to replace the old one.

So, i wanna know if this action can generate a conflict me as I continue to work with both applications.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Because the new app use that cacerts @BoristheSpider

Comment: This seems like a dirty hack - I certainly wouldn't want to change the trusted CAs for _all_ applications on a web server because one webapp needs to trust some dodgy CA. For client-certificate authentication, you can set a separate truststore. For application specific code, consider using a custom truststore that you load and manage in-app.

Comment: what happens If put the cacerts that they given to me? I work for the same company but the new app needs that cacert @BoristheSpider

Comment: Excuseme, how can i set that cacerts to a specific web project? @BoristheSpider